# Make a string represent an array

Tags: java

I have an array

```
String myArray[]={"one","two","three","four"};
```

In my code I am using a string with the same name as the array.Is there anyway to make that string point to the array?

```
String theArray = "myArray";

theArray[0];
```

Is this even possible?

Comment: myArray[0] will give the first index value "one", why do you want to place the variable name in the string?

Comment: I am getting a string from some user input.The string they input is the same as an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this even possible?

No.

You could use a `Map<String, String[]>` to map a name to an array.

A small example:

```
String[] myArray = {"one","two","three","four"};
Map<String, String[]> map = new HashMap<String, String[]>();
map.put("myArray", myArray);
String[] temp = map.get("myArray");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(temp));
```

will print:

```
[one, two, three, four]
```

Comment: can you please post an working example for this so that it can handy for future reference.

Comment: Thanks,What if we wanted to use the array itself.Like myArray[0].

Answer (score 1):

If `theArray` is a field variable - yes, via reflection. But it is not advisable. Use a `Map` isntead.